# how can I redirect input from syslog

Tags: syslog

I installed ganglia and gmond spam the syslog in a way which makes it unreadable (hundreds messages per second)

I wanted to redirect these messages to own log file by adding this to rsyslog config:

```
:rawmsg,contains,"gmond" /var/log/gmond.log
```

this made gmond.log and started filling it with gmond logs but it didn't stop them from being written to syslog file as well.

How do I redirect, not duplicate, the messages?

Answer (score 1):

Add `& ~` in the line below that.